# Can't mount ISO files over a network in Windows 8.1

Tags: networking, windows-8, mount, iso-image, windows-8.1

Ever since upgrading to Windows 8.1, I have been unable to mount ISO disk images over a network. When I try, I get the error "Sorry, there was a problem mounting the file."

I didn't have this problem before upgrading to Windows 8.1. The network files are on a Mac, if that matters, running Mac OS X Mavericks (released a few days ago), although I assume that this is not related.

Comment: If you copy one of the troublesome ISOs to the Windows PC, can it mount it then?

Comment: Yes, it mounts if I copy it to the local PC. But of course, I'd rather have it as it was before, and be able to mount it over the network.

Comment: I've also noticed that I can't view large video files over a network in VLC, when I was able to before. So perhaps this is a broader problem than I thought, and is related to how Windows 8.1 handles loading large files over a network. Because I can read small text files just fine over a network.

Comment: Could it be that the problem is actually in Mavericks, not Windows 8.1?

Comment: Any possibility of mapping the network location as a drive?

Comment: Yes now that I think of it, the problem could be with Mavericks and how its SMB2 server is setup. It used to use SMB, but now in Mavericks it uses SMB2. Also, I'm already using a mapped network location as a drive.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the problem isn't actually related to accessing large files in general (which you are suggesting in a comment above) you might want to try [ImDisk](http://www.ltr-data.se/opencode.html/#ImDisk). ImDisk is a small and lightweight utility for mounting disk images, including CD/DVD as well as HDD images. It might have better luck mounting the image than Windows' own mounting tool.

Comment: I can confirm that I've mounted .iso successfully from the network disk with ImDisk.

Comment: I can confirm too from the network or an other mounted image.